# How to use getPosition() to get the ListView value?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, position

In Activity **WorkDetailsTable** , it has a `ListView` as shown below. When it is clicked, it should  display the value on the **Add_Details_Information** `EditText`

[image]

Assume the first list is clicked, and it intent to  **Add_Details_Information**

[image]

Noted that the value on editText was actually get from the second list in **Activity A**. But what I want is get value accordingly to their position not the latest value.

**WorkDetailsTable**

```
int mClickedPosition;
MyCustomBaseAdapter objMyCustomBaseAdapter;
ArrayList<SearchResults> results=new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                // how to getPosition???
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), Add_Details_Information.class);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProject", ReceiveProject);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveDescription", ReceiveDescription);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProgress", ReceiveProgress);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveTimeIn", ReceiveTimeIn);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveTimeOut", ReceiveTimeOut);
                i.putExtra("date",date);
                i.putExtra("status", status);
                startActivityForResult(i,PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Add_Details_Information**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_details_information);
        addItemsOnSpinner(); // Spinner for project/service/training
        tp = new TimePick(); // call tmePick
        description=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextWorkDescription);
        timeIn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TimeIn);
        timeOut=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TimeOut);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarPercentage);
        progressText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textProgress);
        progressText.setText("Covered:" + "" + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {
            final String Project1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveProject");
            final String Description1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveDescription");
            final int Progress1=getIntent().getIntExtra("ReceiveProgress", 0);
            final String TimeIn1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveTimeIn");
            final String TimeOut1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveTimeOut");


           // project.setText(Project1);
            description.setText(Description1);
            seekBar.setProgress(Progress1);
            timeIn.setText(TimeIn1);
            timeOut.setText(TimeOut1);
            seekBar.setProgress(Progress1);
            progressText.setText("Covered:" + "" + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

        }
```

**MyCustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView in WorkDetailsTable


        private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
            searchArrayList = results;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return searchArrayList.size();
        }



        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchArrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

       public void addNewItem(String P,String D,int Per,String I,String O)
      {
        SearchResults obj=new SearchResults();
        obj.setProject(" Project/Service/Training : "+P);
        obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
        obj.setProgress(" Progress : " + Per);
        obj.setTimeIn(" Time In : " + I);
        obj.setTimeOut(" Time Out : " + O);
        searchArrayList.add(obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtProject= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListProject);
                holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListDescription);
                holder.txtProgress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListProgress);
                holder.txtIn=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListTimeIn);
                holder.txtOut=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListTimeOut);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtProject.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProject());
            holder.txtDescription.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
            holder.txtProgress.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProgress());
            holder.txtIn.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTimeIn());
            holder.txtOut.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTimeOut());

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtProject;
            TextView txtDescription;
            TextView txtProgress;
            TextView txtIn;
            TextView txtOut;
        }
    }
```

**Trying Code**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
      Object o=listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
        SearchResults fullObject=(SearchResults)o;
        String ReceiveDescription=((SearchResults) o).getDescription();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), Add_Details_Information.class);

        i.putExtra("ReceiveDescription", ReceiveDescription);

        startActivityForResult(i,PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: It depends on your ListView `Adapter` implementation. What kind of adapter is backing your listview?

Comment: @TimMalseed customBaseAdapter

Comment: @TimMalseed need to use results.get(position)?

Comment: I would suggest adding a method to your adapter `getIem(int position)` which returns the `SearchResult` for that position (results.get(position)). Then you can access your search result fields from that object.. `getAdapter().getItem(position)...`

Comment: @TimMalseed Thanks for your suggestions.  So now I need to call  `getIem(int position)` in `onItemClick` ?

Comment: You would call getItem(int position) anywhere where you'd like to retrieve the SearchResult from a specific position in the list's adapter. If that's in your onItemClick method, then yeah, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have solved it by using another method